Limitations of getSignatureForAddress
The issue is that when I get the create pool txn, there is no way getting the signatures for the token address going forward in time.
getSignaturesForAddress only goes back in time using the before parameter.
Is there not way to get the transactions for a token after a specific signature?
And would it be possible to start the call at a specific slot number. So if i enter a slot number it starts the scan from that slot

The until parameter will do exactly what you want. You specify a signature, and getSignaturesForAddress will stop once it sees that signature, ie:
curl https://api.devnet.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getSignaturesForAddress",
    "params": [
      "Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111",
      {
        "until": "2QKPPw7ZEF5ZTkSsvt3YgqyEWQp61k8upaeCrpLvzPvVUdANYx7VWyouMArVF4chW6vDQp1DcbjSpDBMcToB31Uz"
      }
    ]
  }
'

There's no way to specify the search start at a specific slot unfortunately.
More info at https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/getsignaturesforaddress

Thanks,
Could you let me know how to get value to use in the until param?

It will heavily depend on your use case. You might be listening to transactions over a websocket to get signatures, you might be fetching blocks, etc. Can you ask a separate question with more information to get a more specific answer?
